# How to push a View Controller after CXAnswerCallAction

Tags: ios, swift, callkit

I am trying to display a specific view controller once a user answers the call using CallKit. Currently, in the CXAnswerCallAction I am trying to use:

`if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(URL(string: "URLgoesHERE://")!) {
   UIApplication.shared.openURL(URL(string: "URLgoesHERE://")!)
} //replaced my URL Schema for question`

But I am getting the following error:

`failed for URL: "URLgoesHERE://" - error: "This app is not allowed to query for scheme URLgoesHERE"`

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add your URL scheme to the `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` key inside your `info.plist`?

> LSApplicationQueriesSchemes (Array - iOS) Specifies the URL schemes
>   you want the app to be able to use with the canOpenURL: method of the
>   UIApplication class. For each URL scheme you want your app to use with
>   the canOpenURL: method, add it as a string in this array. Read the
>   canOpenURL: method description for important information about
>   declaring supported schemes and using that method.

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009250-SW14